# Video Recorded Through Python Script is Too fast

Tags: python, python-3.x, screen-recording

i had a question that i have a python script below and this script uses some modules to record my windows computer screen but i have a problem that the video is recorded and saved but it is too fast
my script:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, 30.0, (1280, 720))
while True:
    img = ImageGrab.grab()
    img_np = np.array(img)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    cv2.imshow("Screen", frame)
    out.write(frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So Please help me How Can I Solve This Issue
Thank You In Advance For Replying

Comment: too fast means the recorded video is too fast

Comment: You should put a slight delay in the `while` loop. If you want 30FPS, then you should do `time.sleep(1/30)` (don't forget to `import time`)

Comment: Thank you So Much... The Best I Could Pray For You is You And Your Family Stay Safe From Corona...

Comment: Thank you, you too!